# SP running very slow in Azure DW even with tables with HASH distribution on unique column

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have a stored procedure in AZURE DW which runs very slow. I copied all the tables and the sp to a different server and there it is taking very less time to execute. I have created the tables using HASH distribution on the unique field but then also the sp is running very slow. Please advice how can I improve the performance of the sp in AZURE DW.

Comment: May well get a better answer over on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: please explain with some examples and share more info on dtu level

Comment: Azure SQL DW doesn't really have a physical server. The server is a logical container that has zero impact on performance so I don't really understand what you mean when you say you moved to a different server and it takes less time to execute. Please provide more details and be explicit about the actions you've taken. Also, what DWU level are you on, what resource class is the user running the query in. How many rows, how many GB/TB?

Comment: @SQLmojoe Different server means when I moved the tables and sp to the On Premise server which we were using earlier. In that server the sp runs very fast but in Azure DW it gets very slow. We are currently using 100 DWU and smallrc resource class (business restraint). The size of the tables vary from 50 - 1000 rows. I tried to change the resource class from smallrc to mediumrc or largerc but getting error using "User or role 'xxxxx' does not exist in this database". How to check which user or role is actually being used when the sp runs and how to upgrade the resource class for that?

Answer (score 1):

From your latest comment, the data sample is way too small for any reasonable tests on SQL DW. Remember SQL DW is MPP while your local on-premises SQL Server is SMP. Even with DWU100, the underlying layout of this MPP architecture is very different from your local SQL Server. For instance, every SQL DW has 60 user databases powering the DW and data is spread across them. Default storage is clustered column store which is optimized for common DW type workloads.

When a query is sent to DW, it has to build a distributed query plan that is pushed to the underlying DBs to build a local plan then executes and runs it back up the stack. This seems like a lot and it is for small data sets and simple queries. However, when you are dealing with hundreds of TBs of data with billions of rows and you need to run complex aggregations, this additional overhead is relatively tiny. The benefits you get from the MPP processing power makes that inconsequential.

There's no hard number on the actual size where you'll see real gains but at least half a TB is a good starting point and rows really should be in the tens of millions. Of course, there are always edge cases where your data set might not be huge but the workload naturally lends itself to MPP so you might still see gains but that's not common. If your data size is in the tens or low hundreds of GB range and won't grow significantly, you're likely to be much happier with [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/).

As for resource class management, workload monitoring, etc... check out the following links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-concurrency
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-best-practices

Comment: Thanks. This is what i explained to the customer. Significance of Azure DW can only be noticed with huge volume of data. For small set of data DW is doing the same distribution operation which is not needed and hence the execution time is getting increased.

Comment: This does not have to be true.  You can make different index choices, eg heap, or clustered index.  Please post your table DDL, the stored procedure and how many records are in each table and I might be able to help you.

Comment: There is some truth to the comment that there is a certain level over overhead. If you are going to run at DWU 100, which is essentially SMP, you may be better taking a scale up approach with SQL DB. 

If you have a sizeable amount of data, you'll want to scale beyond 100 DWU to realize the advantages of the MPP environment.

If you opt to scale past 100 DWU and are still seeing performance problems, seeing the DDL and the Parallel Execution Plan will be very beneficial for troubleshooting. Also please remember column statistics are very important in this platform.

Comment: @wBob, read the OP's comment. Tables range from 50-1000 rows. It doesn't really matter if you're building heaps or btrees or column segments. The shorter the code path to generate a plan and to execute the query, the better you'll be. The fewer IO requests, the better. At the max 1000 rows the OP has spread over 60 distributions, it'd be pretty hard to find an edge case for that to work well on MPP vs SMP codebase even if you're only using 1 node for the MPP codebase. Anything is possible but why work so hard to fit what wasn't designed to?

Comment: I don't like this answer. If SQL DW performance is no good for small amounts of data then it fails at the first hurdle. When you create a DW from scratch for a new application, you don't have terabytes of data yet, though it would scale up to that amount eventually.  OK, so at some point in the future we have to have a DW, but not when we are starting off? So reporting platforms must change once we pass a threshold? This seems arbitrary and frankly idiotic.